# Rule based symbology does not appear in qfield

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qfield

I have a script I have written in pyqgis which returns values from a layer based on values from another layer as a list. I wanted to set a different color for all the elements in that list using rule base symbology. So far I've managed to do so on QGIS but the results does not appear once on QField (it shows the symbology but chooses 0 objects).
I have tried 2 expressions, both work on QGIS but not on QField:

*last_obs() is the function I have created which returns a list with the objects fid number

1. array_contains(last_obs(),"fid")
2. if( array_find( last_obs(),"fid")<> -1, "fid"= array_get( last_obs(),array_find( last_obs(),"fid")),false)
   any suggestions on how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

QField does not support python scripting. You need to write expressions that filter the dataset. You can nest rules to get more refined results. Try to rewrite your rules using filter expressions only.

Comment: I understand, I believe the script action is too complicated (that is why I wrote it in the first place). do you have any suggestion on how to access only the objects in one layer that answer a criteria of another layer in relation to it? I have a layer of map object which is related to a layer of observations (no geometry), I want the objects of the first layer to be colored differently if there has been an observation in the last couple of days.

Comment: It depends on how the layers are related. If observations in your table are related to features in your geometry layer, perhaps by an ID field, then you could create a relation, and then filter for observations within say 2 days of now.  This would look something like to_date(now() - to_interval('2 days')). To access feaures on another layer use get_feature(). To access attributes of that feature use attributes() variant 2. If you want more specific advice you will need to describe more precisely the data in the table, the data in the layer, and how they are related.

Comment: In my understanding get_feature() only returns the first feature matching the value given, and not all of them or am I mistaken?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So It will not choose all relevant features but rather just one, which was not the purpose